# Python - Files I/O

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io

I'm kind of new to this Python "files" stuff. SO this is the code to retrieve the data from a file called "CabDetails.txt" which has some tabular data like the availability of the car for rent and its ID. I am able to run the program without errors but i am not getting any output. Oh btw, the input is given by the user. I feel i messed up in the for loop or maybe i just messed the whole thing up. Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you. ( NOOB SPOTTED, please spare and help :P).

```
try:
    Details=input("enter details of cab you are looking for:")
    for line in Details:
        open('CabDetails.txt','r').readlines()
    if Details in line:
        print (line)
except IOError:
    print("Error:can\'t find file or read data")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are a few error on your code. First you are looping over each character of the input, second you are reading the file for nothing, you don't assign to a variable, and third bad indentation on the if statement.

```
try:
    details=input("enter details of cab you are looking for:")
    for line in open('CabDetails.txt','r').readlines():
        if details in line:
            print (line)
except IOError:
    print("Error:can\'t find file or read data")
```

Something like this should work.

Comment: Oh yes. Makes sense now. Told ya, I might have messed up the for loop. Thanks a lot Tzomas. I will keep the points in mind. Thank you.

Comment: you're not closing the file

Answer (score 0):

Your code have 2 main problems:

1) You open your file and read all the lines for each "line" you find in `Details`, but I suppose that what you want to do is to read all the lines of a file, then search for lines that contains each element in `Details`. You're not even closing the files you open

2) You are actually searching for each element in `Details`, but, if `Details` is a string, you are actually looping throught each letter.
For example, if `Details = "det1,DET2,Det3"` you will search for all the lines that contain each letter

For solving your first problem, we're going to read all the lines of your file and store them in a list named MyFileRows:

```
with open('CabDetails.txt','r') as f:
    MyFileRows = f.readlines()
```

in this way, the `with` statement automatically close your file, and you have your list.

For your second problem, at first you need to separate your `Details` where a comma occurs (assuming your input is like `det1, det2, det3`) and store this values in a list called MyDetails:

```
MyDetails = Details.strip().split(',') # this variable will look like: ['det1', 'det2', 'det3']
```

and at last you check if which lines containts at least one of your details:

```
for line in MyFileRows:
    if any([detail in line for detail in MyDetails]):
        print line
```

note: in the second line, here, we are using [list comprehension](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

your final code should look like:

```
try:
    with open('CabDetails.txt','r') as f:
         MyFileRows = f.readlines()
except IOError:
    print("Error:can\'t find file or read data")

Details=input("enter details of cab you are looking for:")
MyDetails = Details.strip().split(',')

for line in MyFileRows:
    if any([detail in line for detail in MyDetails]):
        print line
```